# Django registration, primary key issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I have an issue with my authentication process. 
I create a SignIN process giving a user the ability to create an a new account using only his mail, account that will be inactive until he edits it  providing his first name, last name and a password. 
I gave it a try but I go to the URL for edit profile I receive an error related to the PK ..

error:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/registration/users/2/edit/

Django Version: 1.11.3
Python Version: 3.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'registration']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/anaconda/envs/myDjangoEnv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/raphaelbendenoun/Documents/testregis/registration/views.py" in update_profile
  41.         user = get_object_or_440(User, pk=pk) #find user instance by id in db

Exception Type: NameError at /registration/users/2/edit/
Exception Value: name 'get_object_or_440' is not defined
'pk'
```

urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from registration import views

app_name = 'registration'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/edit/$', views.update_profile, name="edit-user-profile"),
]
```

form.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import MyUser
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class Form(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields= ('first_name','last_name','email','password','company')

class InactiveForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields= ('email',)


class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):

    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget= forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name','password')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .forms import InviteForm
from invitations.models import Invitation
from .models import project
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

# Create your views here.

class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'index.html'

class CandidateIndex(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'candidateIndex.html'

class HRIndex(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'HRindex.html'

class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = project
    fields = ['project_name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'


def create_invite(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        invite_form = InviteForm(data=request.POST)
        if invite_form.is_valid():
            email1 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email1']
            email2 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email2']
            email3 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email3']
            email4 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email4']
            email5 = invite_form.cleaned_data['email5']
            for i in invite_form.cleaned_data:
                invite = Invitation.create(i)
                invite.send_invitation(request)
            print("The mail was went")
            #return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk} )
        else:
            print("Your form is not valid")
    else:
        invite_form = InviteForm()
    return render(request, 'team_invite.html', {'invite_form': invite_form})
```

project_detail.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h2>Welcome to your Project {{project.project_name}} Detail page</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="invite-team">
      <a href="{% url 'website:addteam' %}">GOGO</a>
  </div>
</div>




{% endblock%}
```

Comment: you have to add the `pk` in your view (`def update_profile(request, pk):`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass pk variable from urls.py to view method, but your view method did not expect it you have to change your update_profile method signature like so:

```
update_profile(request, pk)
    ....
```

your method has more erros inside like this one:

```
form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.User)
```

it probaly should be:

```
User = get_user_model()
user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk) #find user instance by id in db
form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=user)
```

Comment: Hi Matej, Thx for your answer. Now I get an error : user = get_object_or_440(User, pk=pk) even if I imported in my views: from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, any ideas ?

Comment: Sorry i made typo in my answer it sould by user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk) not user = get_object_or_440(User, pk=pk) i correct my answer.

Comment: I updated with the traceback .. I did not get where is the typo ?

Comment: It's in method name 'get_object_or_440' it should be 'get_object_or_404' or just copy paste code from my answer no it is correct.

Comment: OK I corrected but I still get the same error in the Traceback ;)

Comment: Ok did your's  update_profile method looks like this def update_profile(request, pk)?

Comment: It makes no sence could you udate you whole view.py code in question?

Comment: Nice but code you were asking isn't there right now. :-)

Comment: OK I made it worked ! the link works perfectly .. the thing is I woud like to link the Project PK to the invitation .. and have a url like website/project/31/invite ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154147/discussion-between-ben2pop-and-matj-mihal).